# convert from HDF to GeoTiff

Tags: gdal, modis

I am having some problems with the conversion from HDF to GeoTiff.

I am following the steps described in this [webpage](http://www.ldeo.columbia.edu/res/fac/oceanbgc/Sambrotto_Lab/10text.html).
The problem is that I can't find what is the NDVI subdataset name (XXXX) in order to run the gdaltranslate command.

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff HDF4_EOS:EOS_GRID:"MOD13C2.A2001001.005.2007078152825.hdf"
 :MOD_Grid_monthly_CMG_VI:XXXX modis_ndvi01.tif
```

This is the gdalinfo output for one of the files(MOD13C2.A2001001.005.2007078152825.hdf):

```
E:\GDAL>gdalinfo MOD13C2.A2001001.005.2007078152825.hdf
Driver: HDF4/Hierarchical Data Format Release 4
Files: MOD13C2.A2001001.005.2007078152825.hdf
Size is 512, 512
Coordinate System is `'
Metadata:
  HDFEOSVersion=HDFEOS_V2.9
  LOCALGRANULEID=MOD13C2.A2001001.005.2007078152825.hdf
  PRODUCTIONDATETIME=2007-03-19T19:28:25.000Z
  DAYNIGHTFLAG=Both
  REPROCESSINGACTUAL=reprocessed
  LOCALVERSIONID=5.2.1
  REPROCESSINGPLANNED=further update is anticipated
  SCIENCEQUALITYFLAG=Not Investigated
  AUTOMATICQUALITYFLAGEXPLANATION=No automatic quality assessment is performed in the PGE
  AUTOMATICQUALITYFLAG=Passed
  SCIENCEQUALITYFLAGEXPLANATION=See http://landweb.nascom.nasa.gov/cgi-bin/QA_WWW/qaFlagPage.cgi?sat=terra for the product Science Quality status.
  QAPERCENTMISSINGDATA=0
  QAPERCENTOUTOFBOUNDSDATA=0
  QAPERCENTCLOUDCOVER=0
  QAPERCENTINTERPOLATEDDATA=100
  PARAMETERNAME=CMG 0.05 Deg Monthly NDVI

(...)

Subdatasets:
  SUBDATASET_1_NAME=HDF4_EOS:EOS_GRID:"MOD13C2.A2001001.005.2007078152825.hdf":MOD_Grid_monthly_CMG_VI:CMG 0.05 Deg Monthly NDVI
  SUBDATASET_1_DESC=[3600x7200] CMG 0.05 Deg Monthly NDVI MOD_Grid_monthly_CMG_VI (16-bit integer)
  SUBDATASET_2_NAME=HDF4_EOS:EOS_GRID:"MOD13C2.A2001001.005.2007078152825.hdf":MOD_Grid_monthly_CMG_VI:CMG 0.05 Deg Monthly EVI
  SUBDATASET_2_DESC=[3600x7200] CMG 0.05 Deg Monthly EVI MOD_Grid_monthly_CMG_VI (16-bit integer)
  SUBDATASET_3_NAME=HDF4_EOS:EOS_GRID:"MOD13C2.A2001001.005.2007078152825.hdf":MOD_Grid_monthly_CMG_VI:CMG 0.05 Deg Monthly VI Quality
  SUBDATASET_3_DESC=[3600x7200] CMG 0.05 Deg Monthly VI Quality MOD_Grid_monthly_CMG_VI (16-bit unsigned integer)
  SUBDATASET_4_NAME=HDF4_EOS:EOS_GRID:"MOD13C2.A2001001.005.2007078152825.hdf":MOD_Grid_monthly_CMG_VI:CMG 0.05 Deg Monthly red reflectance
  SUBDATASET_4_DESC=[3600x7200] CMG 0.05 Deg Monthly red reflectance MOD_Grid_monthly_CMG_VI (16-bit integer)
  SUBDATASET_5_NAME=HDF4_EOS:EOS_GRID:"MOD13C2.A2001001.005.2007078152825.hdf":MOD_Grid_monthly_CMG_VI:CMG 0.05 Deg Monthly NIR reflectance
  SUBDATASET_5_DESC=[3600x7200] CMG 0.05 Deg Monthly NIR reflectance MOD_Grid_monthly_CMG_VI (16-bit integer)
  SUBDATASET_6_NAME=HDF4_EOS:EOS_GRID:"MOD13C2.A2001001.005.2007078152825.hdf":MOD_Grid_monthly_CMG_VI:CMG 0.05 Deg Monthly blue reflectance
  SUBDATASET_6_DESC=[3600x7200] CMG 0.05 Deg Monthly blue reflectance MOD_Grid_monthly_CMG_VI (16-bit integer)
  SUBDATASET_7_NAME=HDF4_EOS:EOS_GRID:"MOD13C2.A2001001.005.2007078152825.hdf":MOD_Grid_monthly_CMG_VI:CMG 0.05 Deg Monthly MIR reflectance
  SUBDATASET_7_DESC=[3600x7200] CMG 0.05 Deg Monthly MIR reflectance MOD_Grid_monthly_CMG_VI (16-bit integer)
  SUBDATASET_8_NAME=HDF4_EOS:EOS_GRID:"MOD13C2.A2001001.005.2007078152825.hdf":MOD_Grid_monthly_CMG_VI:CMG 0.05 Deg Monthly Avg sun zen angle
  SUBDATASET_8_DESC=[3600x7200] CMG 0.05 Deg Monthly Avg sun zen angle MOD_Grid_monthly_CMG_VI (16-bit integer)
  SUBDATASET_9_NAME=HDF4_EOS:EOS_GRID:"MOD13C2.A2001001.005.2007078152825.hdf":MOD_Grid_monthly_CMG_VI:CMG 0.05 Deg Monthly NDVI std dev
  SUBDATASET_9_DESC=[3600x7200] CMG 0.05 Deg Monthly NDVI std dev MOD_Grid_monthly_CMG_VI (16-bit integer)
  SUBDATASET_10_NAME=HDF4_EOS:EOS_GRID:"MOD13C2.A2001001.005.2007078152825.hdf":MOD_Grid_monthly_CMG_VI:CMG 0.05 Deg Monthly EVI std dev
  SUBDATASET_10_DESC=[3600x7200] CMG 0.05 Deg Monthly EVI std dev MOD_Grid_monthly_CMG_VI (16-bit integer)
  SUBDATASET_11_NAME=HDF4_EOS:EOS_GRID:"MOD13C2.A2001001.005.2007078152825.hdf":MOD_Grid_monthly_CMG_VI:CMG 0.05 Deg Monthly #1km pix used
  SUBDATASET_11_DESC=[3600x7200] CMG 0.05 Deg Monthly #1km pix used MOD_Grid_monthly_CMG_VI (8-bit unsigned integer)
  SUBDATASET_12_NAME=HDF4_EOS:EOS_GRID:"MOD13C2.A2001001.005.2007078152825.hdf":MOD_Grid_monthly_CMG_VI:CMG 0.05 Deg Monthly #1km pix +-30deg VZ
  SUBDATASET_12_DESC=[3600x7200] CMG 0.05 Deg Monthly #1km pix +-30deg VZ MOD_Grid_monthly_CMG_VI (8-bit unsigned integer)
  SUBDATASET_13_NAME=HDF4_EOS:EOS_GRID:"MOD13C2.A2001001.005.2007078152825.hdf":MOD_Grid_monthly_CMG_VI:CMG 0.05 Deg Monthly pixel reliability
  SUBDATASET_13_DESC=[3600x7200] CMG 0.05 Deg Monthly pixel reliability MOD_Grid_monthly_CMG_VI (8-bit integer)
```

Comment: What happens if you try the full name 'HDF4_EOS:EOS_GRID:"MOD13C2.A2001001.005.2007078152825.hdf":MOD_Grid_monthly_CMG_VI:CMG 0.05 Deg Monthly NDVI' as input?

Comment: @Chethan S.  My apologies Chethan. I didn't see your comment when I posted my answer. If you would like to post your comment as an answer, I will go ahead and delete mine.

Comment: No worries Cyrus, I am still not sure if it works. I liked your answer and upvoted it too. So please do not delete it. :)

Comment: Thanks guys! Didn't work exactly how you suggested but it was close: 
**gdal_translate -of GTiff HDF4_EOS:EOS_GRID:"MOD13C2.A2001001.005.2007078152825.hdf":MOD_Grid_monthly_CMG_VI:"CMG 0.05 Deg Monthly NDVI" ndvi.tiff**

Comment: @A.R  I took another look at the link that you posted in your question and noticed that it mentions FWTools. I tested the method that Chethan and I suggested on Ubuntu and it worked okay, but I didn't test it with FWTools on Windows. Maybe the input name gets parsed a bit differently using FWTools? In any case, I'm glad you found a solution. I use FWTools at work sometimes and I'm sure I will refer back to your answer sooner or later. Thanks.

Comment: I end up just using GDAL, but yes I am working on windows.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you almost have it. Be sure to add single quotes around the entire input name with double quotes around the hdf file name.

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff 'HDF4_EOS:EOS_GRID:"MOD13C2.A2001001.005.2007078152825.hdf":MOD_Grid_monthly_CMG_VI:CMG 0.05 Deg Monthly NDVI'
```

Hope that helps