# HDF to Geotiff conversion with MRTSwath

Tags: geotiff-tiff, modis, hdf

Can anyone tell the program code or script for converting HDF files to geotiff using MRTSwath tool?

I've downloaded MODIS Files for fog estimation but i couldn't find how to process them.

Comment: see this 
http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/58688/convert-from-hdf-to-geotiff

Comment: You've tagged with gdal, but your question makes no mention of it, just the specific MRTSwath tool. If gdal is sufficient, then this is a duplicate of the question juls links to. If not, please edit your question to remove the gdal tag and specify in the title you want to do this with MRTSwath.

Comment: I used R to convert from HDF to geotiff, I couldn't get any of the tools to work correctly. Let me know if you need help.

Answer (score 1):

Hey if you are using ArcGIS, below link will give you code developed by me which does the same thing that MRT tool does. Modify the paths of your data input and shape file for cliping the desired area.

https://github.com/HGIS4YOU/MODIS_DATA_NDVI_Arcpy-code.git