# extract scientific layers from MODIS HDF Dataeset using Python GDAL

Tags: python, gdal, modis, hdf

I have been trying to extract scientific data layers from MODIS HDF files but without success. Before I have been doing this type of task using Arcpy, but I want the script that I am currently working to be based only in GDAL and not in Arcpy so I can easily share it. 
I used GDAL, but it seems that GDAL version in windows does not have support for HDF files (I browsed some forums about it). I tried to open the HDF file using gdal.Open() but it does not return anything, and I am pretty sure that my directory path to the HDF file is correct. 
Then I tried pyHDF. So this packages allowed me to extract the scientific layers as 2D array, but I have a problem how to save it as GeoTIFF file. I am aware that for me to save a 2D array to a GeoTIFF file I need some reference, such as projection and raster properties, just like the GetGeoTransform() module in GDAL. In this step, I am not sure how to extract that same kind of information using pyHDF.

Comment: Have you viewed this post. I seem to remember that I did hdf to geotiff in windows with GDAL for some MODIS data in Windows. http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/58688/convert-from-hdf-to-geotiff

Comment: Yes HDF is included with the OSGEO4W version of GDAL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are working with a GDAL version that supports HDF5 datasets this is how you can extract a single subdataset from it and convert it to Geotiff in Python. This example was used for MOD09 and MOD13 band extraction (hence the no_data value conversion).

```
from osgeo import gdal
import numpy as np

def hdf_subdataset_extraction(hdf_file, dst_dir, subdataset):
    """unpack a single subdataset from a HDF5 container and write to GeoTiff"""
    # open the dataset
    hdf_ds = gdal.Open(hdf_file, gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
    band_ds = gdal.Open(hdf_ds.GetSubDatasets()[subdataset][0], gdal.GA_ReadOnly)

    # read into numpy array
    band_array = band_ds.ReadAsArray().astype(np.int16)

    # convert no_data values
    band_array[band_array == -28672] = -32768

    # build output path
    band_path = os.path.join(dst_dir, os.path.basename(os.path.splitext(hdf_file)[0]) + "-sd" + str(subdataset+1) + ".tif")

    # write raster
    out_ds = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff').Create(band_path,
                                                  band_ds.RasterXSize,
                                                  band_ds.RasterYSize,
                                                  1,  #Number of bands
                                                  gdal.GDT_Int16,
                                                  ['COMPRESS=LZW', 'TILED=YES'])
    out_ds.SetGeoTransform(band_ds.GetGeoTransform())
    out_ds.SetProjection(band_ds.GetProjection())
    out_ds.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(band_array)
    out_ds.GetRasterBand(1).SetNoDataValue(-32768)

    out_ds = None  #close dataset to write to disc
```

edit: This answer used GDAL version 1.9.

Comment: Hi Kersten, i tried your code but I am getting an error in the band_ds=gdal.Open(hdf_ds.GetSubDatasets()[subdataset][0], gdal.GA_ReadOnly). I am not sure what is wrong with my processing. hdf_ds = "folder\\path\\MOD.yyyydoy.hdf", band_ds=gdal.Open(hdf_ds.GetSubDatasets()["250m 16 days NDVI"][0]) and it returns 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'GetSubDatasets'. I tried to open my file using % gdalinfo file.hdf in the commandline and it returns the information from my hdf file.

Comment: Hi Kersten, it is working if I am using gdal bundled with QGIS. But with my separate installation of GDAL it is not working.

Comment: Then your other installation likely doesn't support the HDF driver. check with `gdalinfo --formats`

Comment: Hi Kersten, my GDAL driver supports HDF4 (ros), HDF4Image (rw+),HDF5 (ros), HDF5 (image). However, I am not sure if what GDAL installation my command prompt is accessing. I have GDAL bundled with QGIS and I also have separate installation of GDAL from GIS internals.

Comment: Thanks for your script it works. I am using gdal 2.2.2 and it seems the `GetGeoTransform()` and `GetProjection()` are coorectly extracted from the source data, but not applied to the result. The output is unprojected. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 8):

Here is my code I use to convert all HDFs in a folder to GeoTIFF via GDAL (OSGEO4w) in Windows when working with SST data. Remember to use the OSGEO4W version to get hdf support.

```
for %A in ("C:\temp\*.hdf") do gdal_translate -of GTiff -a_srs "+init=epsg:4326" -a_ullr -180 90 180 -90 -co "COMPRESS=PACKBITS" -sds "%A" "%A.tiff
```

`for %A in ("C:\temp\*.hdf") do` Loop through all files in the folder with .hdf extension.

`gdal_translate -of GTiff` Convert all files in the selected folder to GTiff.

`-a_srs` Set the WGS 1984 projection to all the Gtiffs.

`-a_ullr` Set the bounds of all the Gtiffs.

`-co` Compress all the Gtiffs.

`-sds` Convert all files in the hdf, subdataset.

TIP

Use `–ot Float32` for floating point we are in Integer.

Comment: hi, how do I convert just a specific SDS?

Comment: -sd 1 -sd 2 and so on http://www.gdal.org/gdalinfo.html

Comment: hi, it does not work.. I get this - ERROR 6: Unknown option name '-sd'. If I write -sds I get: ERROR 6: Too many command options

Comment: what version are you using of gdal?

Comment: I'm using gdal version 2.1.4

Comment: paste your entire code

Comment: I execute this code from anaconda command prompt and it works but for all sds. `for %A in ("C:\Users\try\*.hdf") do gdal_translate -of GTiff  -sds "%A" "%A.tiff` . I can't figure out how to modify it so it will extract only specific sds

Comment: I think it is  
for %A in ("C:\Users\try\*.hdf") do gdal_translate -of GTiff -b 1 "%A" "%A.tiff  so b 1 for band 1 b2 for band 2 and so on.

Comment: no.. I get: `Input file contains subdatasets. Please, select one of them for reading.` I've tried also to use capital 'b', and add 'sds'..

Answer (score 2):

for extracting all the layers, I used this code

```
for %i IN (*.hdf) do gdal_translate -sds %i %i.tif
```

Comment: using bash, this one worked:


     `for i in *.hdf; do gdal_translate -sds $i $i.tif; done`