# INSAT 3D data in HDF to GeoTiff?

Tags: geotiff-tiff, hdf

I am working with INSAT3D Images from mosdac for air quality monitoring as my final thesis. I had downloaded the data from mosdac which are in HDF format and i tried to convert it to GeoTiff using HEG tool, but the operation failed since the pixel size which have to give in  the geotiff for the conversion was incorrect.

Is there any software for the conversion of HDF image for INSAT3d to a Geotiff file other than HEGtool?

If not can anyone let me know the pixel size which have to give in  the geotiff for the conversion?

Comment: Please rework your title and question so that it is not a duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/58688/convert-from-hdf-to-geotiff . HDF can mean many things

Answer (score 1):

You can use the trial version of FME Desktop.
https://www.safe.com/fme/fme-desktop/trial-download/